# Shell script does not get parameters

Tags: linux, shell

I have this script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

usage () {

echo "Usage: $0 {saludar}"
exit 1
}

saludo() {

a=$1

echo "hola" $a

}

case $1 in
"saludar") saludo;;
*) usage;;
esac
```

I don´t know why $a is always empty.

Comment: Because you don't pass any parameter to `saludo`. Hence, `$1` is empty, and for this, `a` is empty too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the second parameters as an argument to the function:

```
case "$1" in
    saludar) saludo "$2" ;;
    *)       usage ;;
esac
```

Comment: Looking at the `usage`,  we see that there is no second parameter expected. I think the OP should think first, how his script is supposed to be used.